# a suitable fitness function for finding deadlock in a graph

Tags: genetic-algorithm

I have written a genetic algorithm for searching a node in a graph with no outgoing transition,
One of the fitness functions is that we consider the number of outgoing transitions and the chromosome with least value is considered as the best.
My question is that what are the other fitness functions?

Comment: This is quite a broad question that you are asking.  Could you please describe the problem in greater detail and the work that you have done so far?

Comment: I want to search a graph using Genetic Algorithm to reach a node with no output edge (a leaf) but I don't want to search all paths to reach a leaf so I use Genetic Algorithm. I have considered the cost function of a path is the sum of the outputs of all nodes in it. I want to know what other cost functions I can use. Thanks